# convergence in distribution: does the mean converge?

Tags: probability, distributions, convergence, measure-theory

Disclaimer: this is a double-post from math.stackexchange. I'm not sure if it belongs to stats or math... Thank you so much for your help!

Let $z_n\equiv \min\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ where $x_i$ i.i.d. with continuous PDF $f(\cdot)$ over a compact support [0,1] such that $f(0)=\lambda>0$. I know that the random variable $nz_n$ converges in distribution to $Z \sim  exp(\lambda)$ (exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$).

Question: what condition can I impose on $f(\cdot)$ so that we have that $E[nz_n ]\to E[Z]=1/\lambda$? It can be shown easily that when $f(\cdot)$ is uniform, the claim is true. I couldn't show that it is true in general.

To see that $nz_n\to^{dist} Z$, let the counter-CDF of $nz_n$ be $G_n(z)$. Since 
$$nF(z/n)=\int_0^zf(u/n)du \to f(0)z=\lambda z, $$we have $G_n(z)\equiv (1-F(z/n))^n\to\exp(-\lambda z)$.

Comment: You should not double post.  Pick one site and if it is off topic you can migrate to the other.